# What do I get 'Uncaught TypeError: results is not a function' when using map function

Tags: javascript

Just going through the map function and don't understand why I get
`[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]` even after supplying the `this` value for use of the callback, like the doc says...

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

var results = numbers.map(
  function(foo){
  console.log(foo * foo);
 }, results
);
results();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Makes sense, you are returning nothing, thus `undefined`.

Comment: Please understand what `map` does before attempting to use it blindly. Otherwise, don't be surprised if it doesn't work like you want.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Also, where are you getting the error mentioned in the title?

Comment: @ Felix In the console.

Comment: And as `map` returns an **array**, it's not going to to work to try to then call it as a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you pass to `map()` needs to return the result you're after.

```js
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var results = numbers.map(function(num) {
  return num * num; 
}); 

console.log(numbers);
```

Your function as it is doesn't explicitly return, so it is returning `undefined` at the end of each invocation.

From [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a cleaner way:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

var getValues = function(data){
    console.log(data)
    return data;
    // do whatever with the array's values
}

numbers.map(getValues);
```

Comment: This will also return an array filled with `undefined`. You aren't returning anything.

Comment: No it won't @Oriol, why?

Answer (score 2):

> Why do I get 'Uncaught TypeError: results is not a function' when using `map` function?

Because `Array.protoypte.map` will **NEVER** return a function.

> [**15.4.4.19 Array.prototype.map ( callbackfn [ , thisArg ] )**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19)
>
> *callbackfn* should be a function that accepts three arguments. `map`
>   calls *callbackfn* once for each element in the array, in ascending
>   order, and constructs a new Array from the results.